# Can I use the Shrink Method for the whole document in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I don't know anything about code. I work with e-learnings in Storyline 3. I sometimes localize these e-learnings and use the translation tool in Articulate which basically exports an MS Word file. Sometimes the target languages are longer and I need to decrease the font size by percentage for the whole document. Usually, there are at least 3 different font sizes that I need to decrease accordingly. I am wan to develop a macro that I will use for multiple documents.

I couldn't find a way to do this by percentage, but looks like the Shrink or Grow Methods will do the work! I found this code in the reference page but looks like it works only for a selected object. The issue is that the exported MS Word file is in a table with each text box in the storyline separated to a cell. When I select the whole table it does not work.

```
If Selection.Type = wdSelectionNormal Then 
    Selection.Font.Grow
Else
    MsgBox "You need to select some text."
End If
```

Could you please help me and let me know if this would be possible for the whole document, or the selected table? It would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could probably do this with a macro, no coding required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear from your question whether the table in the Word document contains the actual text boxes or just the text they contain.

If it is just the text then `Shrink` may work. I tested this on a document with a single table containing only text:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Font.Shrink
```

Comment: They say not to comment only with Thanks, but there is not way not to thank you m4o_tim - you saved me a lot of time :)